# Optimising python function with numba

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numba

I am trying to speed up a python function using numba, however I cannot seem to make it compile.
The input for my function is a 27x4 array of type np.int32.
My function is:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def edge_profile(input):
    pos = input[:,:3]
    val = input[:,3]
    centre = np.mean(pos,axis=0).astype(np.int32)
    diff = np.absolute(pos-centre).sum(axis=1)
    cell_edge = np.zeros(3)
    for i in range(3):
        idx = np.where(diff==i+1)[0]
        idy = np.where(val[idx]==1)[0]
        cell_edge[i] = len(idy)
    return cell_edge.astype(np.int32)
```

However this produces an extremely large error message which I have unable to use to diagnose the problem. I have tried specifying the input types as follows:

```
@nb.jit(nb.int32[:](nb.int32[:,:]))
def ...
```

however this produces an equally large error message.
I fell that I am probably using some function/feature that is not supported in numba, but I do not know enough about it to identify the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Numba should work ok so long as you stick to basic lists and arrays in the function you want to speed up. It appears that you are already using functions from  `numpy`  that are probably already well optimized. So its unlikely you will see a speed up even if you did get it to work. You haven't mentioned what your OS is. Under ubuntu 14.04 you can get it to work through some steps outlined [here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2016/10/the-magic-of-numba-and-python.html#.WB_zbXUrKbk).